# Assigning Permissions to Folders in AWS

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In one of application developed using Asp.Net, I want to allow users to upload documents/ images to a specific folder. I am getting error access denied while uploading to the folder. How can I grant write permissions to the folder. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the folder, select Properties, and then select the Security tab. Click Edit. In the Permissions dialog box, select DefaultAppPool (or any other application pool you use) and then select the Write check box in the Allow column.
More information can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-setting-folder-permissions-6-of-12).

Comment: the application is hosted on AWS

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to upload in javascript from the web browser?  Or is the server (ASP.NET) application uploading?

S3 resources are private by default.

## Server Upload

Assuming it is your ASP.NET server application that is uploading the files to the bucket, you have some options.

#### Bucket Policy

You could use a bucket policy to allow certain IAM users write access. For example, the IAM user your ASP.NET application has credentials for.
This tutorial explains how to do this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example1.html

#### User Policy

Alternatively you could attach a policy to the IAM user that your ASP.NET application has credentials for.
This tutorial explains how to do this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex0

## Client Upload

If you want the client (javascript) application to do the upload and authenticate each end user, look at IAM Web Identity Federation. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc.html

Comment: I have made few folders in the application where users will be uploading the images and other files from the application (asp.net). I am confused here. if I am going to create a Bucket policy, how do I map these folders with the buckets where I will assign the permissions. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Sorry, because you tagged the question with s3 I incorrectly assumed you were uploading the files to Amazon S3. You should consider using the AWS SDK and storing the files in S3. It will scale better than storing them in a folder on an EBS volume.